# Add a 'Buy-it-Now' button to an ApacheSolr View

Tags: ubercart, search, views

So I have built a View that uses Apache Solr to display products on my Ubercart site from the Solr index.  Swell.  Now Ubercart typically lets me add a 'Buy-it-Now'/ Add to Cart button as a field in most views but for some reason in this view that is not possible.

How do I add a 'Buy-it-Now'/ Add to Cart field to this view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I was not able to try out gj. 's answer because I figured this out using the [Views Field View](https://drupal.org/project/views_field_view) module.

I created a sub view called 'Buy it now Button'.  This view displays just a buy it now button field with one result that takes a contextual filter with Node ID as an argument.  I added the view 'Buy it now Button' as a field in my faceted search view and everything works fine.

The only thing extra to note was that I had to add an invisible Node ID field to the search view which I could then pass as an argument to the View Field (conditional arguments are supported by Views Field View)

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the hooks provided by apache solr to alter your search results : `hook_apachesolr_process_results`

and you could append 'Buy it Now' button as well by using `hook_theme()`

[Apache solr hooks](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!apachesolr!apachesolr.api.php/7)

Comment: I did not get a chance to attempt your answer; however, I feel like if my problem was a little more complicated these options would have come in handy.